# How to convert decimal to binary using pythons basic fuctions

Tags: python-3.5

I'm trying to convert decimal to binary, binary to decimal, and to create a binary counter. Because it's for school, we are only allowed to use while and for loops, if, if-else, if-elif-else, int(), input(), print (), range(), pow(), len(), and str(). We are not allowed to use break, continue, quit(), or exit() statements, or return statements to break out of a loop. We also cannot use any functions that were not listed in the allowed section, like bin, etc. I'm struggling to come up with a way to convert decimal to binary this way. Does anyone have an idea on where to start? I've created the selection menu for the converter, but haven't been able to create the converter. Any tips on where to start would be helpful.

Comment: Do you know how to do it by hand?

Comment: I can do it by hand, but don't know how to translate that to idle.

Answer (score 0):

Decimal to Binary Algorithm

Lets say you have a number n,

```
till n>0:
  n%2 ( will give you the remainder)
  n = n/2
```

reverse the results obtained through n%2 to get the Binary equivalent of decimal.

Try working out decimal to binary and vice versa step by step by hand. Then it should be easy to code.